# How to store an ArrayList<View>

Tags: android

I have a viewPager with an ArrayList with all the Views inside, when i change orientation everything resets.
I've looked on Google but I've found only ways to store string and int arrays, but not views

How can i store the ArrayList during orientation changes? The number of the views in the array can change

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Retaining an Object During a Configuration Change

> If restarting your activity requires that you recover large sets of
>   data, re-establish a network connection, or perform other intensive
>   operations, then a full restart due to a configuration change might be
>   a slow user experience. Also, it might not be possible for you to
>   completely restore your activity state with the Bundle that the system
>   saves for you with the onSaveInstanceState() callback—it is not
>   designed to carry large objects (such as bitmaps) and the data within
>   it must be serialized then deserialized, which can consume a lot of
>   memory and make the configuration change slow. In such a situation,
>   you can alleviate the burden of reinitializing your activity by
>   retaining a Fragment when your activity is restarted due to a
>   configuration change. This fragment can contain references to stateful
>   objects that you want to retain.

The essence is to use

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

You can read more about it here [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject)

Comment: I had my fragment already set to setRetainInstance(true) but my variable was stored in the adapter so it got reset every time

Answer (score 0):

If you have to store View in ArrayList then you have to declare in onSaveInstanceState method
I have add small example how to store arraylist onSaveInstanceState Method.

```
@Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            arList=new ArrayList<String>();
            arList.add("1");

            arList.add("2");
    //putStringArrayList
            outState.putStringArrayList("test", arList);
        }
```

And In OnCreateView getting stored ArrayList

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
//Checking arrayListexist or not in Landscape or portrait mode
                arList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("test");
                if (arList != null) {
                    Log.d("tag", "arrList" + arList.get(0));
                }else{
                    arList=new ArrayList<String>();
                }
            }
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
```